# std::vector Offset Calculation for VBO?

Tags: c++, opengl, stdvector, vbo

I'm using a VBO with an interleaved array to render a obj (model format) iv loaded. Is this possible to do with a vector instead? The GL code works with using a vector but the offset for a vector of vectors is going to be quite different. So the buffer doesn't step through the vector correctly. Therefore renders nothing but is created.
So my normal code for a VBO is(with some irrelevant bits missed out):

```
#define BUFFER_OFFSET(bytes) ( (GLubyte*) NULL + (bytes) )
    //define interleaved array
    GLfloat Cubedata[12][4] = 
    {
        //tu   tv     Cr     Cg     Cb     Ca     Nx     Ny     Nz     Vx     Vy     Vz
        +0.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f, +1.0f, -0.5f, +0.5f, +0.5f,//top left     0
        +0.0f, +0.0f, +1.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f, +1.0f, -0.5f, -0.5f, +0.5f,//bottom left  1
        +1.0f, +0.0f, +1.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f, +1.0f, +0.5f, -0.5f, +0.5f,//bottom right 2
        +1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f, +1.0f, +0.5f, +0.5f, +0.5f //top right    3
    };
   //define other stuff

        //create vbo
        glGenBuffersARB(2, VBOid); //generates ids for the buffers
        glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, VBOid[0]);//specifes the current buffer object
        glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, ( (4 * 12) * sizeof(GLfloat) ), *Cubedata, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);

        glInterleavedArrays(GL_T2F_C4F_N3F_V3F, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0) );//set offsets
        //bind indicies
        //bind current buffer, render
```

this works perfectly for an array of GLfloat type but with a vector of GLfloat it doesnt. The vector definition needs to have twelve columns and nth rows such as:

```
vector< vector<GLfloat> > vec_interleaved(12,vector<GLfloat>(4) );
```

so getting to the point of my question, how do you calculate the offset for a vector? in this case I want the buffer to start reading from every 12 elements / the start of every row.

Comment: I think there'd be a problem. When you have an array, the memory is contiguous. With the vector in vector scheme, it is not. And you cannot guarantee that the offsets will be contiguous either, since the memory for the vector-in-the-vector is allocated on the heap.

Comment: Why not just do vector<GLfloat> vec_interleaved(12 * 4) ?

Comment: @Robert: I just tried that, checked the data was going into the vector correctly, doesn't seem to make a difference. If the array was defined on the heap would that work with a vbo?

Comment: @QuantumKarl data is data, regardless of where it is stored. You are just simply seeking data that is contiguous. 
As an aside, how about sizeof(CubeData) instead of (4 * 12) * sizeof(GLfloat)?

Comment: @Daniel & Banthar: ok so I've changed the code above to: 
vector<GLfloat>vec_interleaved(12*4);
glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, ( sizeof(vec_interleaved) * sizeof(GLfloat) ), &vec_interleaved, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);
the only problem is that there is no casting for vector to GLvoid * as the method wants so if i replace &vec_interleaved with (GLvoid *)vec_interleaved i get a compile error, so its not possible? :/

Comment: @QuantumKarl that should be glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vec_interleaved.size() * sizeof(GLfloat),  &vec_interleaved[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply, you can't.
The vector of vectors is essentially storing a vector of pointers to memory elsewhere, and is therefore not contiguous and cannot be offset.

You will need to use a multi-dimensional array; as you are already.

Comment: on Cplusplusrefrence.com it says "Vector containers are implemented as dynamic arrays; Just as regular arrays, vector containers have their elements stored in contiguous storage locations, which means that their elements can be accessed not only using iterators but also using offsets on regular pointers to elements." so wouldn't pointer arithmetic work?

Comment: @QuantumKarl It works within single vector. If you have vector of vectors, you have many different vectors and pointer arithmetic won't work between them. I think you should use `vector<GLfloat[12]>`, so number of columns is constant while number of rows can grow.

Comment: @Banthar: so if i used a 1D vector, would the offset be the same as it is for the array like above?

Comment: @QuantumKarl `vector` uses array internally, so the offset between elements should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a one dimensional vector:

```
std::vector<float> data;
int data_width;

float atXY(std::vector<float> &v, int x, int y)
{
    return data[data_width*y + x];
}
```

It makes sense to derive from std::vector to add multidimensional support. But of course this is such a common task, that it has been implemented by somebody already. Namely the Boost libraries have it:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html

Comment: I'm not allowed to use boost libraries for my acw since someone else has done some of the hard work :(

Comment: @QuantumKarl: Wrapping this yourself is not hard work, actually. Indeed if I were your teacher, you using a well tested library instead of rolling your own would earn you extra points (unless the library implemented the main topic of the assignment).